# Subtract 1 year from dates in YYYYMM format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a pandas string that actually represents as date in YYYMM format:

```
date_have=201903
```

What I want is to convert to a date 12 months prior:

```
date_want=201803
```

How can I do that? The datatype of date_want should be numeric.

Answer (score 3):

You will need `pd.offsets.DateOffset` here, because a timedelta of "1 year" is not a fixed amount of time.

```
s = pd.Series([201903])

0    201903
dtype: int64

# convert to datetime
dates = pd.to_datetime(s.map(str), format='%Y%m')
# subtract a year and convert back to YYYYMM format
(dates - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1)).dt.strftime('%Y%m').astype(int)

0    201803
dtype: int64
```

---

As a scalar, the solution is almost the same, just without the `.dt` accessor.

```
date_have = 201903
date_want = (
    pd.to_datetime(str(date_have), format='%Y%m') - pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=1))

int(date_want.strftime('%Y%m'))
# 201803
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems too good to be true:

```
date_want = pd.to_numeric(date_have) - 100
```

Comment: This might seem smart but you usually don't want to handle dates like this, especially when the format is subject to change anytime.

Comment: Of course, it's specific to this question. I wouldn't want my date in `YYYYMM` as type `int` anyway.